# No overwrite on Ant UNZIP

Tags: ant, unzip

I want to unzip a file, but if some file exists, this mustn´t be replaced.

I tried this:

```
<unzip src="compress.zip" dest="dirTo" overwrite="false">
<patternset>
    <include name="dirFrom/**"/>
</patternset>
```

"dirFrom", is the name from the directory IN the compress file, what I want to extract. I use "overwrite" to false, but it doesn´t work, and it ovewrites.

I have a directory, and this has different subdirectories. I want one of those subdirectories, with it´s files and sub-subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it.

1st, I extract everything to auxiliar directory.
2nd, I make a loop, to compare file by file, if that file exists.
3rd, If the file doesn´t exists, I copy it.

```
    <unzip src="compressFile.zip" dest="dirAux">
    <patternset>
        <include name="mySubDir/**"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>

<fileset id="fileset1" dir="dirAux/mySubDir" />
<property name="newContentMySubDir" refid="fileset1"/>

<for param="nameFile" list="${newContentMySubDir}" delimiter=";">
    <sequential>

        <if>
            <not><available file="${finalDir}/mySubDir/@{nameFile}" type="file"/></not>
            <then>
                <copy tofile="${finalDir}/mySubDir/@{nameFile}" file="dirAux/mySubDir/@{nameFile}"/>
            </then>
        </if>

    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Ok that should work, but it uses ant-contrib library. By the way, I think that my solution works too, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, that didn´t worked for me. I tried it, but it didn´t work. It overwrote everything.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overwrite` to false will only prevent to overwrite destination file if it is newer than source file. For more complex filtering, you have to use `copy` task with a `zipfilset` as it is explain in ant documentation (see [unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) task -- in section `Related tasks`). For exemple, following code should not extract files from a zip file if they already exist in the destination directory (respecting source directories layout):

```
<copy todir="${target.dir}">
    <zipfileset src="${zip.file}">
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </patternset>
        <present targetdir="${target.dir}" present="srconly"/>
    </zipfileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn´t work. I changed "<zipfileset dir=" to "<zipfileset src=", but it didn´t work yet. Maybe, the problem, is that I have a little elaborated structure. I show it in an edit up.

Comment: yes, my mistake, you have to use `src` attribute for the zipfileset , I will amend my example. The example above works only if files are in exactly the same structure as in the zip file: for instance, it will prevent to write file 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' if and only if file `${target.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is present.